# Changing content of iframe dynamicallly

Tags: html, iframe

I have a bit different task to do,

first, i have add an iframe tag dynamically, which i was able to do easily using the code->

```
function getFrame()
{
    var iframeTA = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframeTA.setAttribute("src", "iframeTakeAction.html");
    iframeTA.style.width = "200px";
    iframeTA.style.height = "200px";
    document.getElementById("status").appendChild(iframeTA);      
}
```

now, want i want to do is to access the elements of iframeTA (i.e. elements within the body tag of 'iframeTakeAction.html' which is the source of iframeTA),
something like this -> 
**iframeTA.body.getSomeElement......**

Hope this kind of operation is possible, if so please put some light.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access it with:

> document.getElementById("TOUR IFRAME ID")

However, this only holds as long as your iframe src is a relative path on the same domain. If you change the domain then your browser will prevent you to do this.